# Duplicate records being returned from JoinTable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have three tables: `Users`, `Groups`, and `GroupUsers`, with `GroupUsers` being a join table between the other two. When using the following method to find all users for a specific tenant,

```java
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
List<User> findAllByTenantId(String tenantId);
```

I am getting back a duplicate of the first user.

Here are the definitions for the columns:

```java
    @NotNull
    private String tenantId;

    @ManyToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "GroupUsers",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userUuid", referencedColumnName = "uuid"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "groupUuid", referencedColumnName = "uuid"))
    private List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();
```

```java
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<User> members = new ArrayList<>();
```

I am using the following test. I know it is coming from the join because if I remove the GroupUsers insertion, the correct number of Users are returned.

```java
    @Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, statements = {
            "INSERT INTO Tenants (tenantUUID, name, domain, companyId, adminConsentGranted)" +
                    "VALUES ('tenantId1', 'tenantId1', 'tenantId1domain', 123, 1)," +
                    "('tenantId2', 'tenantId2', 'tenantId2domain', 124, 1);",
            "INSERT INTO Users (companyId, tenantId, uuid) VALUES " +
                    "(123, 'tenantId1', 'uuid1')," +
                    "(124, 'tenantId1', 'uuid2')",
            "INSERT INTO Groups (companyId, tenantId, uuid, displayName)" +
                    "VALUES (123, 'tenantId1', 'groupuuid1', 'group1')," +
                    "(124, 'tenantId1', 'groupuuid2', 'group2');",
            "INSERT INTO GroupUsers (userUuid, groupUuid) " +
                    "VALUES ('uuid1', 'groupuuid1'), " +
                    "('uuid1', 'groupuuid2');"
    })
    @Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD, statements = {
            "DELETE FROM GroupUsers;",
            "DELETE FROM Groups;",
            "DELETE FROM Users;",
            "DELETE FROM Tenants;"
    })
    @Test
    public void testFindAllByTenantId_groupMembership() {
        List<User> users = userRepository.findAllByTenantId("tenantId1");
        assertEquals(2, users.size());
    }
```

Also, for context, this issue started occurring when moving to a new Spring Boot version (2.7 to 3.0) and changing `javax` dependencies to `jakarta`, e.g. `jakarta.persistence.JoinTable`.

I've seen some suggestions about changing the `List<User>` to a `Set`, or using `FetchType.LAZY`. Changing the fetch type allows the test to pass, but I am trying to understand what changed between these versions, and if the new fetchtype could cause issues.